# How can I control the workflow of siuba in Python using a config file to specify column names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to control the workflow of python siuba from a config file. I do not want to specify source column names directly in code, but keep them separate in a config file. Once the file is conditioned, the code will use the internal column names. Suppose I have:

```
import pandas as pd
from siuba import *
import yaml

data = pd.DataFrame({'student university':['electrode', 'hard knocks'],
                     'student GPA':[3.5, 3.9],
                     'student name':['Neo', 'John Wick']})

config = """
columns:
    "student university": university
    "student GPA": gpa
    "student name": name
"""
config = yaml.safe_load(config)
```

I want to do something like this:

```
(students = data
    >> select([_.f'{k}' == _.f'{v}' for k, v in config['columns'].items()])
)
```

to end up with columns: ('university', 'gpa', 'name') for this simple example. My question is specifically about using siuba. I know how to do this using pandas directly.

================

Update:
I am able to perform select using a config file by:

```
students = (data >> select([_.__getattr__(f'{k}') == _.__getattr__(f'{v}') for k, v in config['columns'].items()])
```

However, I also want to do things like mutate, which looks something like:

```
students = (data >> mutate(gpa = _.gpa / 4.))
```

I can resolve the right hand side by:

```
students = (data >> mutate(gpa = _.__getattr__(config['mutate']['column']) / config['mutate']['divisor'])
```

Assuming I already resolved that this was a division operation. I still need to workout how to get the first gpa in the mutate from a config file.

=================

Update2 (resolved): You can create a dictionary and pass it in as **kwargs to mutate.